# Wordpress website transferring from wamp to xamp

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, xampp, wamp

How to transfer a wordpress website from WAMP to XAMPP? I am having website backup file but I don't have database sql file.

Answer (score 0):

The same guide below will work.

https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/transfer-wordpress/

You may have to take a backup of your mysql database using phpmyadmin ( or Command line - Read https://codex.wordpress.org/Backing_Up_Your_Database )

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you use wamp/xampp and you use MySQL for database, then this url working for you: localhost/phpmyadmin

Export the database what you want from wamp and import to xampp!

Or if you have small DB, just copy the whole SQL code from export window and paste to xampp PHPMyAdmin SQL windows and run!

So start wamp (stop xampp is running) go to localhost/phpmyadmin,
click Export tab,
select the DB what you want to export and click Run,
if your DB not too large, just copy to clipboard the exported SQL code!

Then stop wamp and start xampp and go to localhost/phpmyadmin,
click on SQL tab,
paste SQL code from clipboard and click Run!

That's all.